# Integer.parseInt Returns an error: The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (R.string)

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, int

I have to build an array of some structures that i've built:

The class (Item) is built the following way: (It is shown below)

Now my problem is that im trying to parse some string number that Im getting from another place (a list in this case) to int.

But I get this error:

> The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for
>   the arguments (R.string)

This is the piece of the code:
(It says the error is in ("Integer.parseInt"):

```
markers.add(new item(Integer.parseInt(items.get(0).get(i)), items.get(1).get(i), items.get(2).get(i), items.get(3).get(i), Integer.parseInt(items.get(4).get(i)), Integer.parseInt(items.get(5).get(i))));
```

its just long but its not complicated.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

the items list is just a list of lists:

```
List<List<string>> items;
```

and the structure of the class is:

```
private int id;
private string title;
private string desc;
private string pub;
private int p;
private int n;
```

the code:

```
public List<List<String>> Download()
    {
        String data = null;
        //String res = "";
        try {
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();// Reference to the Internet
            httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();// get the content of the
                                                        // message
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs,"iso-8859-1"));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

            String l = " ";
            // String nl=System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l + "\n");
            }
            data = sb.toString();
            webs.close();

            List<List<String>> all= new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            all.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            all.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            all.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            all.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            all.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            all.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            all.add(new ArrayList<String>());

            try {

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("item");
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //res += json_data.getString("title")+"\n";
                    all.get(0).add(json_data.getString("id"));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //res += json_data.getString("title")+"\n";
                    all.get(0).add(json_data.getString("title"));

                }
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //res += json_data.getString("title")+"\n";
                    all.get(0).add(json_data.getString("desc"));

                }
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //res += json_data.getString("title")+"\n";
                    all.get(0).add(json_data.getString("pub"));

                }
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //res += json_data.getString("title")+"\n";
                    all.get(0).add(json_data.getString("p"));

                }
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //res += json_data.getString("title")+"\n";
                    all.get(0).add(json_data.getString("n"));

                }

                return all;

            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }

            //return news;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            int x=3;
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please show your items list

Comment: where you add the elements in the list.

Comment: Im parsing them from a JSON string with an httpRequest into "items". then Im supposed to arrange them in a List of my own structure.

Comment: can you show me that code

Comment: Please check the string number which you are adding in the list

Comment: I've pasted the whole httpRequest code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change Your code,
 Use String insted string.

```
 private int id;

private String title;

private String desc;

 private String pub;

private int p;

private int n;
```

also change list

```
List<List<String>> items;
```

Answer (score 1):

The type that you use, `string`, is apparently not `java.lang.String`, so you cannot give it as argument into `Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String)`.

Answer (score 1):

Other way of doing the same without changing your code is , you should call getString() in parseInt() so that getString() will return you java.lang.String, something like this :

```
   getString(R.string.value);
```

Doing this will save your lot of efforts of replacing `string with String.`

If you open the R class you will see that it contains only numbers that are references to the compiled resources of your project.

Choice is yours :)

Cheers